# Searching if File does exist

Tags: ruby, file

I'm programming a music player that reads in data from a 'data.txt' file (not the problem) then stores it an array with records in it called Album, which includes title, artist.... and tracks. In the tracks record, it includes the track name and track location.

In the code below, im trying to search for the track, for example \music\album1\song_name1.mp3, but this is returning as false in the IF statement event though the file exits.

```
def playTrack(track, album)
  if File.file?(album.tracks[track].location)
    puts "Found"
    @song = Gosu::Song.new(album.tracks[track].location)
    @song.play
  else
    puts "Not found"
    puts album.tracks[track].location
  end
end
```

Comment: The issue is surely with relative paths. Try to `puts Dir.getwd` ([`Dir.getwd`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Dir.html#method-c-getwd)) and figure out what’s wrong.

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but IIRC Ruby uses `/` as a path separator on windows too.

Comment: @Jakevarrese : I'm sure your path is wrong. After you see the message _Not found_, what exactly is printed? I suggest that you replace `puts album.tracks[track].location` by `p album.tracks[track].location`, so that you REALLY see what's in this variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Using p instead of puts help me see that there was a \n after the string. Everything works fine now.

Just did . chomp  on the string to fix